# How to customize java log file to contain at most N log records only instead of size in bytes

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging

I am using [java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) to generate log files. It make use of **FileHandler** to write write records into the log files. 
The FileHandler class contains limit parameter to decide when to create new file in case size (in bytes) of the current log file has exceeded the limit.

Is there any way we can override the behavior of limiting the file handler to some other parameter instead of size? like - maximum N number of records in each log file. If there comes (N+1)th record a new file log file is generated.
In case can't be achieved using standard java.logging, is there any other open source implementing this behaviour (like log4j or any other opensource logger)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileHandler can be extended to listen for a rotation by overriding the `setLevel` method.  Then force the FileHandler to always rotate by setting the limit to one byte and then prevent the rotation from happening if your conditions are not met.

Here is a sample solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;


public class CountingFileHandler extends FileHandler {

    private static final RuntimeException PREVENT_ROTATE = new RuntimeException();
    private final long maxRecords;
    private long count;

    public CountingFileHandler(String pattern, long maxRecords, int files) throws IOException {
        super(pattern, 1, files, false);
        this.maxRecords = maxRecords;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setLevel(Level lvl) {
        if (Level.OFF.equals(lvl)) { //Rotation sets the level to OFF.
            if (++count < maxRecords) {
                throw PREVENT_ROTATE;
            }
            count = 0L;
        }
        super.setLevel(lvl);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
        try {
            super.publish(record);
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            if (re != PREVENT_ROTATE) {
                throw re;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
        CountingFileHandler cfh = new CountingFileHandler("test%g.log", 2, 5);
        cfh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cfh.publish(new LogRecord(Level.SEVERE, Integer.toString(i)));
        }
        cfh.close();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you just want some max limit for a single log file you can just install [com.sun.mail.util.logging.DurationFilter](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/util/logging/DurationFilter.html#DurationFilter-long-long-) with a duration of `Long.MAX_VALUE`. That filter is included in the [`javax.mail.jar` or the `logging-mailhandler.jar`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  This solution won't provide the rotations you want.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i wanted.